# Google Analytics - comparing metrics for different cities approach

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics

I receive traffic from a number of different cities across the world, these being: Washington, Bratislava and Belfast.

In Google Analytics, I would like to be able to compare a variety of metrics (side by side), however i'm not sure how to go about this in the best way.

Am I looking at creating 3 advanced segments, 3 profiles or should I be doing it in one custom report?

Or is this even possible in Google Analytics version 5?

Comment: It would help if you could tell us which metrics are you specifically looking at. The custom report is possible. However without any more information, the 3 advanced segments approach is best.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply achieved by using segments where you include City Exactly Matches .

You can apply up to four segments at any one time. Note that segments are now setup under the profile (they moved them a while back).

You can apply these segments to most of the default views and/or your own custom reports. (Note that Google's identification of geographic areas can vary in accuracy depending upon the country.)